# How implement filter in datagridview from a text box?

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview which display the data was imported from an excel file.
I also have a search box (text box) I want to type in the text box then it filter automatically the data inside the  datagridview.

I search around and see people use the data table but I don't know how can I implement that in my program.

Here's my code:

```
 private void runFileImport()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;

        int xlRow;
        string fileName = "";
        xlApp = null;
        xlWorkbook = null;
        xlWorkSheet = null;
        xlRange = null;


        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Excel office |*.xls; *xlsx";
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        fileName = ofd.FileName;

        if(fileName != "")
        {
            dgvData.Rows.Clear();
            dgvData.Refresh();

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            try
            {
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
                xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            // Read values from settings
            string startTime = Properties.Settings.Default.startTime;
            bool isHighlightLt = Properties.Settings.Default.highlightLt;
            bool isCalculateLt = Properties.Settings.Default.calculateLt;

            string lt = "";
           
            int i = 0;

            for(xlRow = 2; xlRow <= xlRange.Rows.Count; xlRow++)
            {
                

                if (xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 1].Text != "")
                {

                    string clockIn = xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 3].Text;
                    
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(clockIn) == false)
                    {
                        DateTime work_start = DateTime.Parse(startTime);
                        DateTime employee_start = DateTime.Parse(clockIn);

                        if ((employee_start > work_start) && isCalculateLt)
                        {
                            lt = employee_start.Subtract(work_start).ToString().Substring(0, 5);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lt = "";
                            
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        lt = "";
                    }

                    i++;
                    dgvData.Rows.Add(i, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 1].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 2].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 3].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 4].Text, lt);
                 
                }

                var liteRed = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fccaca");

                if (isHighlightLt)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow myrow in dgvData.Rows)
                    {
                        if (myrow.Cells[5].Value.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = liteRed;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where you're adding rows to the `datagridview`, for example: `dgvData.Rows.Add` you should be using a class to store your data and then put into a collection of some sorts. Then you can bind the collection directly to the `datagridview`. Finally you can filter that data how you need. On the other hand, the way you're doing it now, makes this much harder; you can still do it, loop through the rows and check what you need to based on your conditions. TBH this is too broad and or would be an opinionated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it step by step.

Start with putting all of your excel data into a dataset.
Then you create a DataView from the DataSet with something like `DataView dView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;`
You connect the DataGridView to the DataView with something like `myDataGridView.DataSource = dView;`
This DataView can be filtered through [`RowFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-6.0).